# Should ajax error reponseText come back as JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending a multipart form-data request w/ ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/postit',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {

      },
      error: function(response) {
         // response.responseText is json, but not parsed
      },
      data: someFormData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
```

I was hoping the error response would be parsed as it is JSON.  Looking at the response headers from the request in chrome I see:

```
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I have tried setting dataType: 'json' with no luck either.  I suspect this is just a difference in how the error object is treated.

Is there a way to get the JQuery ajax call to automatically parse that error response into a JS object?

Comment: It sounds like you have double encoded your response. Post the response or better the code that generates it.

Answer (score 0):

The error callback will give the following parameters:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // ...
}
```

Where `jqXHR` is a superset of the native [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which means that `responseText` is a DOMString.

While the success callback will give:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
// ...
}
```

Where `data` could be anything, parsed according to content type.

> [XMLHttpRequest.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) <kbd>Read only</kbd>
>   Returns a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) that contains the response to the request as text, or null if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

Comment: agree, with all of that.  was hoping I missed something.  I will parse the response content-type header to determine if its json and parse myself.  Seems like something that would be built into jquery so really thought I was missing something.

Comment: @lostintranslation IDK of any way to get the parsed data in the error callback.